# Reading a registry key results in "The file type being saved or retrieved has been blocked" error

Tags: windows, rust, registry, registrykey

I'm trying to read a registry key value and it fails even when I run app as an Administrator:

```
extern crate winreg;

use winreg::enums::{HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, KEY_READ};

fn main() {
    let hklm = winreg::RegKey::predef(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);
    let subkey = hklm
        .open_subkey_with_flags(
            r#"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"#,
            KEY_READ,
        )
        .expect("Failed to open subkey");
    let u_uac_status: String = subkey.get_value("EnableLUA").expect("Failed to read");
    let mut r_uac_status: String = String::new();
    if u_uac_status == "1" {
        r_uac_status = String::from("Enable");
    } else {
        r_uac_status = String::from("Disable");
    }
    println!("UAC status: {}", r_uac_status);
}
```

The error I get:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to read: Os { code: 222, kind: Other, message: "The file type being saved or retrieved has been blocked." }', libcore\result.rs:1009:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
error: process didn't exit successfully  (exit code: 101)
```

Comment: Maybe an AntiVirus program problem? Try to disable yours and try again

Comment: @hellow, it's not Antivirus problem.

Comment: `let r_uac_status: String = if u_uac_status == "1" { "Enable" } else { "Disable" }.into()`; is shorter, more efficient, and doesn't require mutability.

Comment: @codexy please [edit] your question to show how you know it's not antivirus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to read a `String`, but the registry contains an integer value. Try with:

```
let r_uac_status = subkey.get_value::<u32, _>("EnableLUA")
   .map (|u_uac_status|
         if u_uac_status == 1 { "Enable" } else { "Disable" })
   .expect("Failed to read");
```

Note: you don't even need administrator rights to read the value.